# How to navigate page with Vaadin menubar?

Tags: grails, vaadin, menubar, redraw

These are my first steps with java, I took grails and vaadin plugin. I want to make simple app with menu bar navigation, so I have got some Vaadin example:
http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#BasicMenuBar

created some commands:

```
edit.addItem("Cut1", menuCommand1);
edit.addItem("Cut1", menuCommand1);
```

Each command just draw table from another example:

http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#TableHeaderIcons

Unfortunately each time I hit menu item it draws one table under another table, but what I was expecting is to draw each table in place of previous one.
How to achieve this?

Comment: maybe you save items in database and then update for new ones? Try to delete all before putting new objects.

Comment: while many things still hold true for vaadin7 from the vaadin6 sampler, you might be better off picking examples/code/inspirations from the new one http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vaadin's UI is stored as state (in a session) on the server.  if you add several items they stay unless removed.  so e.g. if you want to replace the table there you two options.  either [`removeAllComponents`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.5/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponentContainer.html#removeAllComponents%28%29) and then add the new one or if you have hold of the original table then you can [`replaceComponent`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.5/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractOrderedLayout.html#replaceComponent%28com.vaadin.ui.Component,%20com.vaadin.ui.Component%29) in the wrapping layout (most likely a VerticalLayout?).

if the table is just supposed to change content, then you are better off to just change/modifiy the dataSource of the table.

Comment: Would I need to create my menubar each rime I click something in menu?

Comment: no, the menu bar would be part of the state (unless of course, you added the menubar to the same layout as the table and you now call the removeAllComponents on that very layout).

Comment: I think public void replaceComponent(Component oldComponent,
                             Component newComponent) is a way to go, I just need to figure out how to store "last chosen component".

Comment: if you know its the last component or all except the first, the container also has getters by index and an iterator.  quite common one stores the data in a private var.  the more advanced usecase is to use a Navigator (which in your case would lead to writing a renderer for it -- slightly more advanced)

Comment: I moved some lines around, and now it works with removeAllComponents, so no need for Navigator :-). No I am directing my efforts into "How to fill tables with data, and make it editable".
Thanks for all your help.